# Calculating probability of normal distribution

Tags: probability, statistics

$P(-1.475<Z<1.475)$

$=2P(Z<1.475)$

$=2(0.93)$

$=1.86$

But probability can't be greater than 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that:

$$P(-1.475<Z<1.475) = \Phi(1.475)-\Phi(-1.475).$$

Taking into account that $\Phi(-1.475) = 1- \Phi(1.475)$, then the last equation is

$$2\Phi(1.475)-1.$$

Answer (score 2):

No. It should be $1-2P(Z\geq1.475)$.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you meant $P(-1.475<Z<1.475) = 2P(0<Z<1.475)$, which is correct due to the symmetry of the standard normal distribution.

Make sure you are reading your table correctly.